# Time complexity of function calling another function?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I know how to find the time complexity for almost any option (simple function, function with loops, etc.), but I can't figure out how to determine time complexity of function that is calling *another* function, specifically if the calling function is inside a loop.

I wrote some functions, that I use as example.

```
int g(int k) {
  int i=0;

  while(k>0) {
    i += k;
    k= k/2;
  }

  return i;
}

int f(int n) {
  int m = 0;

  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    for (int j=i; j<n; ++j) {
      m += g(j);
    }
  }

  return m;
}
```

I can't figure out: do I have to consider the time complexity of function `g()`, and if I have to how to calculate it in function `f()`? Or do I just ignore function `g()` and include just the function calls in function `f()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As, the function g's complexity depends on the parameter k (logarithmic), you have to consider it while calling it from function f. In case, if g's worst case operation has constant time complexity, then you may not need to consider it explicitly.

In your case, f's complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>) & g's complexity is O(lg(n)), yielding an overall complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>lg(n))

Comment: f's complexitiy is O(n^2 ln(n)) it would be O(n^2) if g had constant complexity

Comment: Agree with tobi303, if function g had constant complexity, then the overall complexity would be O(n^2).

Comment: Then why do you write "f's complexity is O(n^2)" ? That is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take account complexity of `g` in `f`.

`g` has `O(log(n))` complexity.

so complexity of `f` is the sum of those complexity `log(j)`s.

At worst it is `O(n²log(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the complexity of f, just inline the code of g inside f, and think as if this was a single whole function. The call himself is O(1) and thus has no impact on complexity, it's as if the code inside g was executed at the place where g is called.

This would be untrue in some cases, for instance if you pass by value an array of size n as a parameter to the function : in this case, the array copy itself would be O(n), so the call would have some effect on complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This is intuitively n²log(n), but more precisely, you get the following proof:

[image]

[image]